# Janerik plum from seeds

Tags: germination, plums

I'm trying to grow janerik plums from seed.

All of the online advice I've seen is about European plums (e.g. the "paper towel and water in a ziplock bag in the fridge" thing), and this is what I am trying, but is this correct for janerik? Lebanon has snow, so perhaps freezing is in order?

**EDIT**

Good question about the botanical name. I honestly don't know; my house came with the tree, and everyone keeps asking for seedlings.

The majority opinion seems to be that it's a *prunus cerasifera*, similar to cherry plums. They are green, but turn redder when they are ripe (i.e. when it's too late; they are best eaten unripe). But reports are conflicting, so don't take my word for it.

**ADDENDUM**

Well, I've just tried air layering. Wish me luck!

Comment: Can you by any chance advise the botanical name.  Digging online ther e seem to be a few things which are called Janerik, and which are different cultivars (eg Sour Green Plums or Sour Cherry Plums.  If they are Goje Sabz / Persian Greem Plums https://www.isons.com/shop/fruit-trees/plums/persian-green-plum-tree/ talks about them growing in zones 5-9 - in which case you would just put them in the fridge....

Comment: I'm not qualified to answer this, but as snow is a very good insulator (ie insulate the ground from sub-zero temps - think igloo) and a fridge is typically just above freezing - about 4c, I'd expect you would NOT want to put them in the freezer as this would likely cause the cells to burst.

Comment: Again, I'm not yet qualified (but I'm on my way there!) - If you want to give people copies of your tree, you would likely be better off using air layering or grafting for 2 reasons - Plum trees don't grow true to type from seed - so the trees you grow could produce quite different fruit, and also it will take many more years to get fruit from a cutting then from a graft/air layer.  (If you are grafting, you need to ensure the rootstock is compatible - so air layering is likely a better way to go.

Comment: If you are seeding, the simplest chilling hack is to copy nature by planting the seeds outside now and digging them up as they sprout in the Spring. For air layering, you could score and wrap a single branch every foot or so.

Comment: @YosefBaskin I live in the Southern Hemisphere.

Comment: It it's Summer, you can try your chilling technique with some seeds and nature for the others. I never found chilling works for perennials or apple seeds.